# Geographic Clustering by Values and Coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, gis, hierarchical-clustering

I have a set of polygons with specific values in a shp file. (geographic data with lon lat coordinates)
The goal is to assign these polygons to clusters.
The polygons must be neighbours to each other.
These polygons have specific values in the column "num_points".
There is a specific threshold of 100 to 150 points in sum per cluster that must be respected.

I have tried to use dbscan to cluster the data but this approach has failed, because i didn't found a way to make the threshold a parameter in the script.
What alternatives are there? i have been thinking about Quadtrees and Geohashes to cluster the polygon but they both have their specific sets of limitations.

I am looking forward to any help ! Thanks a lot in advance :)